# create fake anomalies in dataframe - pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

in order to implement unsupervised random forest learning - i want to label the trained data as clean , and create fake data , based on that data, but with anomalies between it's features , so the model will detect these rows as anomalies.
something like is done with following with rdd on the features column (vector):

```
columns = df.first()
new_df = None
for i in range(0, len(columns)):
    column = df.sample(withReplacement=True, fraction=fraction) \
        .map(lambda row: row[i]) \
        .zipWithIndex() \
        .map(lambda e: (e[1], [e[0]]))
    if new_df is None:
        new_df = column
    else:
        new_df = new_df.join(column)
        new_df = new_df.map(lambda e: (e[0], e[1][0] + e[1][1]))
return new_df.map(lambda e: e[1])
```

but i want to implement it with dataframe API , not with rdd.
anyone has a clue how to do that ?
i figure that doing it with dataframe api will be a lot faster on pyspark....

Comment: What does df schema look like here?

Comment: label - string & features - vector. it is after featureHasher and Scaler steps